# the min value 40 and max value 60 in the function. how I can fixed that?

Tags: javascript

I have issues in this line of my code :

```
var randomNumber = function(40, 60) {
  var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (21)) + 40;

  return value;
};
```

the min value 40 and max value 60 in the function. how I can fixed that?

Comment: You can simply do `40+Math.random()*20` following the formula **min_value + Math.random()*(min_value-max_value)**

Comment: You can get answers very easily with a simple search. Please try to find enough before posting your questions.

Comment: the error say Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

randomNumber(40, 60);
```

You need to call the function with params 40 and 60.

Answer (score 3):

do this:
after some researching I found that for random numbers between two int values you need to do like that:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Hope it fix your problem.

Comment: then call the function like this: `var num = getRandomArbitrary(40, 60);`

Comment: and you NEVER get `max` as an answer. Should the answer be int or float

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that takes the min and max parameters and operate them this way:

```
function randomIntegerNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
randomIntegerNumber(40,60)
```

If you want to return always a number between 40 and 60 use:

```
function randomIntegerNumber() {
  const min = 40;
  const max = 60;
  return Math.ceil(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Math.random() returns a value between [0, 1), one is not included, that is the reason to use Math.ceil(), it will aprox a float number to its next integer.

```
Limits:
If Math.random() = 0,
then 40 + 0 * (20) = 40,
Math.ceil(40) = 40

If Math.random() = 0.9999 (aprox 1)
then 40 + 0.9999 * (20) = 59.998000000000005,
Math.ceil(59.998000000000005) = 60
```

Math.ceil() transforms any float number to its next integer number (59.99 -> 60)